# Visual Studio Code - debug

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use the debugger in vs code.
I have problems to activate and run it.

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])}


int arr [] = {54,25,7,2,12,65};
 for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    printf("%d ,",arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");
insertion_sort(arr,6);
for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    printf("%d ,",arr[i]);
}

return 0;}
```

This is my JSON file.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
    }
]}
```

I'm getting this error: Unable to start debugging. program path is missing or invalid.

Thx!

Comment: this program has syntax errors. you cannot debug a program that doesn't compile.

Comment: I can run this program, it's working but I want to debug her.